# like/dislike button with api call not working using vue an mongoDB

Tags: vue.js

I am learning vuejs and i am working on my first project which is a social network, and i want to implement a like button that call the api to add a like or remove it if the user has already liked it. It does work in my backend but i can't make it work in the front.
I need to send the userId and add or remove the like  when i click on the button

This is the data

```
data() {
        return {
            post: {
                file: "",
                content: "",
                likes: 0,
            },
            showModal: false,
            showModifyPost: false,
            user: {
                firstname: "",
                lastname: "",
                _id: "",
            },

        };
    },
```

the last method i tried

```
likePost(id) {
            axios
                .post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/post/like/' + id, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
                    },
                })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("response", response);
                    this.user._id = response.data._id;
                    if(post.usersLiked == user._id) {
                        this.post.likes += 0
                    } else if (post.usersLiked != user._id) {
                        this.post.likes += 1
                    };
                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
```

and this is the model

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userId: { type: String, required: true, ref: "User" },
    content: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    imageUrl: { type: String, trim: true },
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    usersLiked: [{ type: String, ref: "User" }],
    firstname: {type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    lastname: {type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    created_at: { type: Date},
    updated_at: { type: Date }
});
```

Any idea what is wrong ? Thank you !

Comment: Does **DB** update correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work on the front end? A method is not triggered, an API call returns incorrect data, a template is not refreshing?

Comment: It does not update on the DB, and i am getting an error 401 (Unauthorized).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, i changed the axios method to this

```js
likePost(id) {
            let userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
            axios
                .post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/post/like/' + id, { userId }, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
                    },
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.getAllPost();
                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
```

i also made a few changes to the data

```js
data() {
        return {
            posts: [],
            post: {
                file: "",
                content: "",
            },
            showModal: false,
            showModifyPost: false,
            user: {
                firstname: "",
                lastname: "",
                _id: "",
            },
        };
    },
```

and i also made some changes on the controller

```js
exports.ratePost = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body.userId)
    //using findOne function to find the post
    Post.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then(post => {
        if (!post.usersLiked.includes(req.body.userId)) {
            // making a object with $inc and $push methods to add a like and to add the user's id
            let toChange = {
                $inc: { likes: +1 },
                $push: { usersLiked: req.body.userId },
            };
            // we update the result for the like
            Post.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, toChange)
                // then we send the result and the message
                .then(post =>
                    res
                        .status(200)
                        .json(
                            { message: "Liked !", data: post }
                        )
                )
                .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
        } else if (post.usersLiked.includes(req.body.userId)) {
            // using the updateOne function to update the result
            Post.updateOne(
                { _id: req.params.id },
                //  we use a pull method to take off a like
                { $pull: { usersLiked: req.body.userId }, $inc: { likes: -1 } }
            )
                .then(post => {
                    // then we send the result and the message
                    res
                        .status(200)
                        .json(
                            { message: "Post unliked", data: post }
                        );
                })
                .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
.then(() => { // you missed value response from Promise here
  this.user._id = response.data._id;
  if(post.usersLiked == user._id)
})
```

Do you mean `this.post.usersLiked === user._id` I suppose, so post within your **data options** should be

```js
post: {
  file: "",
  content: "",
  likes: 0,
  usersLiked: false,
  // something else reflect to your post schema
},
```

> i want to implement a like button that call the api to add a like or remove it if the user has already liked it

By saying that you just need a simple `boolean` value to do this

```js
likePost(id) {
  axios
    .post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/post/like/' + id, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      // Just need to toggle state
      this.$set(this.post, 'usersLiked', this.post.usersLiked !== response?.data?._id)
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: i am getting an error 401 (Unauthorized). I guess it's because of the token. But every others methods that require a token are working so i am a bit confuse now

Comment: I added this.post next to the api route. The error does not appear anymore but now nothing happens

Comment: You can check your API in tab **network** to see If it has token attach in header or not and response from it.

Comment: i do have a  header with the bearer token and but the response is empty and i dont have a states code.

Comment: but in the usersliked data i am suppose to have all the id of the users who liked it. So doing a boolean might not work right?

Comment: did you try to make request with postman or httpyac? would it result the same? if `usersLiked` is an array then you can check current user exist in that or not by `Array.prototype.some`

Comment: yes i did. This is my postman request to add a like "{
    "userId" : "62d9493a9323aaf438efb204",
    "like" : 1
    }". and this is the content in the usersliked array "usersLiked: ['62d9493a9323aaf438efb204']"